# Extract children with a given condition - Django MPTT and Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-mptt, drf-queryset

[image]

In this tree I want to do a query so that **only** the first generation of the red circle is extracted.
But the condition is that the value of each circle must be greater than zero, ie the green circles:

[image]

Serializers:

```
class CircleBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Circle
        fields = ('id', 'value')


class CircleChildrenSerializer(CircleBaseSerializer):
    class Meta(CircleBaseSerializer.Meta):
        pass

class CircleParentSerializer(CircleBaseSerializer):
    children = CircleChildrenSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta(CircleBaseSerializer.Meta):
       pass
```

View:

```
class CircleViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CircleParentSerializer
    queryset = Circle.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self):
        id = self.kwargs["id"]
        u=Circle.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Certainly result is [5(1,0,3)] that is not desirable.
How can I do this query?

Comment: (Bad implementation) You do not treat MPTT like this in the serializer. Moreover, I would strongly suggest you to use django-mptt within your model and make the logic there.  In addition, if you read the `django-mptt` documentation you will find a lot of functions that help with this issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is late but will be useful for others.
There are many ways to achieve what you are asking, the simple one:

***models.py***

```py
from django.db import models
from mptt import models as MpttModels


class Circle(MpttModels.MPTTModel):

     parent = MpttModels.TreeForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='leaf_nodes'
    )
    value = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        """String representation of model objects"""

        full_path = [self.value]
        next_category = self.parent
        while next_category is not None:
            full_path.append(next_category.value)
            next_category = next_category.parent

        return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])
```

***serializers.py***

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from your_api.models import Circle

class CircleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serialize class of Circle model"""
    
    class Meta:
        model = Circle
        fields = ['id', 'value', 'leaf_nodes']

    leaf_nodes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_leaf_nodes(self, instance):
        """Return all children of instance when condition is true"""

        # You can use get_children() method of ModelSerializer
        # (or you can use related_name of ForeignKey) to serialize
        # reverse relation of ForeignKey field.
    
        return CircleSerializer(
            instance.get_children().filter(value__gt=0),
            many=True
        ).data
```

This serialize class will return parent node (the one you select in view class using queryset for specific 'id') and its children those have value greater than zero.